# Memory Management (Allocating Pages/Frames to Logical Addresses)

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I am new to Operating Systems and I was following this handbook which I am reading to get a better grasp on how computers really work. However having stumbled upon Memory Management I found it somewhat confusing when allocating pages and frames using page tables to virtual memory locations.
Say Page/Frame size is 4K and the system is 32-bit (it handles addresses 4byte long and page entries are also 4byte long).
If the same Process references two different memory locations for its needs say Virtual_MemoryLocation_A is 222 and Virtual_MemoryLocation_B is 999 will these memory requests be pinned to the same Page 0 (first Page in the Page table) since both do not extend beyond the frane size scope of 4096 bytes and be granted memory by the OS to the same Frame X?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a coding or design issue.  It reads more like a no-effort homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a page size of 4096, then

```
page number = address DIV 4096
page offset = address MOD 4096
```

Those two values uniquely identify the logical memory location.

Two addresses can be in the same frame. If that were not the case, there would be no point in having pages. All memory locations from 0 .. 4095 are in the same, zeroth page.

Comment: I detect some fundamental misunderstanding here. Once a logical to physical mapping is defined by a page table, it tends to remain in place. The same frame can be shared by multiple processes in certain circumstances (e.g., shared memory, system memory).

Comment: My bad I've just remembered that internal fragmentation is inevitable and since logical addresses start off from 0 a few or some frames happen to be mostly empty. It's just plain strange my textbook didn't show a page table with multiple logical addresses of the same Page being mapped to the same Frame Number.